# the code doesn't multiply decimal values because of dot

Tags: sql, vb.net, internationalization, decimal, decimal-point

I'm using **SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2008**. Working with `VB.NET` language.
Colums which I set as Decimal in SQL store values using dots, like `"10.5"`
When I try to insert a value in the same format, there is no problem. but when I try to insert it like `"10,5"` then I have **"Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric"**.

What bugs me is, I need to multiply 2 decimal values which I get from textboxes and insert the result in SQL. I tried Decimal.Parse and some other functions work in that way but I always get the same result. `(10.5) * 2 = 210`

Somehow the code eliminates the dot and it sees like the value is 105. When I use comma instead of dot, the code works correctly but it cannot insert and says "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric".

I'm out of options.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the culture you are using

```
d = Decimal.Parse(s, New CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

Or

```
d = Decimal.Parse(s, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

In order to use the culture of your operating system.

---

Note: The database is not storing the decimal with `.` or `,`. It stores it using some binary representation if the column is declared as a `decimal` column. Never store a number in a `varchar` column. The same is true for a `Decimal` variable in VB. It stores the number using a binary representation. The problem of the dot `.` or the comma `,` as a decimal separator (i.e. the problem of the right culture) arises only when converting from and to `String`.

Take care of passing the parameters to your SQL command by using parameters instead of using string concatenation. That way you don't have to be worried about culture related issues when inserting number and date values into a SQL command. It also prevents you from SQL injection attacks and strings containing apostrophes `'` represent no problem either.

Answer (score 0):

`10,5` isn't decimal for computers.

**NEVER** save decimal numbers with the *colon*; it is used to separate functions/values.

And about the `10.5*2 = 210`, it is probably a problem parsing your `dec` value. I don't code `vb.net`, but it may be simply dropping the `.` to calculate it with an `int`

Comment: `10,5` is decimal for computers if you specify the right culture!

Comment: With `NEVER save decimal numbers with the colon`, i was reffering to the DB. In the DB it should be saved using a standard ( usually, decimals with _dot_ ) and converting it to the culture **on display**

Comment: NVM, now i understood your comment. I am not sure about how _vb.net_ handles that. But usualy it is safe to save to DB using an standard (usualy International date/number format) and then converting it when you want to show the data

Comment: You have a string from a TextBox. Convert it to decimal using the right culture, then pass this decimal as a parameter to the `SqlCommand` containing an insert or update statement. This does not involve any culture since we are **not** converting the decimal back to string! The parameter is passed as binary data to the command. The database stores the decimal using a binary representation internally. Again no culture involved. The problem arises only if you try to store the number in a varchar column. Don't do it.